# Loading fonts in Python/Pillow on a Mac

Tags: python-imaging-library

The Pillow [ImageFont](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageFont.html) documentation has a few examples of using different fonts, but they don't work "out of the box" on a Mac. It's probably not too hard to figure out where my system fonts are located, but I'm lazy and would like a simple example that I can just edit.

So: how can I use Pillow on a Mac to write some text in a different font and size from the default?

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry, I'd been meaning to test your example, but hadn't got around to it due to (i) currently working on something else, and (ii) being lazy. It works fine, so I've accepted. This has increased your rep by 0.023%.

Comment: Glad it worked for you - thank you for the insight on my rep 

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, "Lazy One" ;-) Here is an example:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

# Make a red canvas and get a drawing context to it
img = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(500, 200), color=(255,0,0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

# Get a "Chalkduster" TTF
chalk = ImageFont.truetype("Chalkduster.ttf",16)

# Get a "Keyboard" TTF
kbd = ImageFont.truetype("Keyboard.ttf",26)

# Make example for Lazy One - showing how to colour cyan too
draw.text((40,40),"Keyboard",font=kbd, fill=(0,255,255))

# And another
draw.text((20,140),"Chalkduster",font=chalk)

img.save("test.png")
```

[image]

If you want a list of all the TTF fonts on your system, you can look in both:

- `/System/Library/Fonts`, and
- `/Library/Fonts`

And, if you are very lazy, you can check in both at the same time from Terminal:

```
find {/System,}/Library/Fonts -name \*ttf
```

**Sample Output**

```
/System/Library/Fonts/SFNSDisplay.ttf
/System/Library/Fonts/Symbol.ttf
/System/Library/Fonts/ZapfDingbats.ttf
/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Braille.ttf
/System/Library/Fonts/SFNSText.ttf
/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Braille Outline 6 Dot.ttf
/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Braille Pinpoint 6 Dot.ttf
/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Symbols.ttf
/System/Library/Fonts/SFNSTextItalic.ttf
/System/Library/Fonts/SFNSRounded.ttf
/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Braille Pinpoint 8 Dot.ttf
/System/Library/Fonts/Keyboard.ttf
/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Braille Outline 8 Dot.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Webdings.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Zapfino.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Trebuchet MS Italic.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Georgia.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Verdana Bold.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Bodoni 72 Smallcaps Book.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Times New Roman Bold Italic.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Silom.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Verdana Italic.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Times New Roman Italic.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Bradley Hand Bold.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow Italic.ttf
/Library/Fonts/AppleGothic.ttf
/Library/Fonts/DIN Condensed Bold.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Farisi.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Arial Bold.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Trebuchet MS.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Mishafi.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Trattatello.ttf
/Library/Fonts/BigCaslon.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Courier New Bold.ttf
/Library/Fonts/NISC18030.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Lao Sangam MN.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Luminari.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Times New Roman.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Brush Script.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Georgia Italic.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Courier New Italic.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Chalkduster.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Apple Chancery.ttf
/Library/Fonts/AppleMyungjo.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow Bold Italic.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Courier New.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Wingdings 3.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Wingdings 2.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Hoefler Text Ornaments.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Bodoni Ornaments.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Skia.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Trebuchet MS Bold Italic.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Impact.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Kokonor.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Tahoma Bold.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Diwan Thuluth.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Ayuthaya.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Khmer Sangam MN.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Trebuchet MS Bold.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Arial Black.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Courier New Bold Italic.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Comic Sans MS.ttf
/Library/Fonts/DIN Alternate Bold.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Wingdings.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Sathu.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Arial Bold Italic.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Tahoma.ttf
/Library/Fonts/PlantagenetCherokee.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Georgia Bold.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Verdana Bold Italic.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Microsoft Sans Serif.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Georgia Bold Italic.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Arial Rounded Bold.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Times New Roman Bold.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Krungthep.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Gurmukhi.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Andale Mono.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Mishafi Gold.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Herculanum.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Comic Sans MS Bold.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Arial Italic.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Verdana.ttf
/Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow Bold.ttf
```