# Can you import your own font into PIL (Python Image Library)?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I was wondering if there was any way to use your own fonts in draw.text. The font I want to use is called DiscoMonkey.

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("[discomonkey font]", 32)
```

Comment: According to the docs, yes you can https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#imagefont-module

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59160253/2836621